# Unable to show BindingMode Enum in comboBox (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, enums

I'm trying to show the original `BindingMode` enum in a comboBox (the list of `TwoWay``OneWay` etc.).

In the `XAML` file, inside `Resources` I need to set `ObjectDataProvider` to be the type of `BindingMode`:

```
<!--BindingMode combo box-->
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="BindingMode" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
    <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        <x:Type TypeName="sys:BindingMode"/>
    </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>
```

The problem is that I can't include `System.Windows.Data` in 'xmlns', i've tried to declare:

```
xmlns:sysWinData="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Data;assembly=mscorlib"
```

but it won't work. What am I missng here? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.Windows.Data` resides in `PresentationFramework.dll` so change your declaration to

`xmlns:sysWinData="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Data;assembly=PresentationFramework"`